# How do I stop the password prompt from displaying again when the correct password is entered?

Tags: javascript

The user has 3 attempts to enter the correct password. I noticed that if the password is entered correctly on the second attempt, the password prompt would still pop up and ask them to re-enter the password. What do I do so that as soon as the correct password is entered, the prompt will no longer pop up?

```js
var correctAnswer = 'mypassword';
var counter = 3;

var guess = prompt('what is your password?');

if (guess !== correctAnswer) {
  while (counter -= 1) {
    counter > 3;
    console.log(`Please re-enter your password. You have ${counter} more attemps.`);
    var guess = prompt('what is your password?');
  }
} else {
  console.log('Password is correct')
}
```

Comment: [Rubber Duck Debug](https://rubberduckdebugging.com) your code. When will the `while` condition be checked? When will the `if` condition be checked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a clearer solution:

```js
var correctAnswer = 'mypassword';
var counter = 3;
var guess;

while(counter--) {
  guess = prompt('what is your password?');

  if(guess === correctAnswer) {
    console.log('Password is correct');
    break;
  } else if(counter > 0) {
    console.log(`Please re-enter your password. You have ${counter} more attemps.`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Upvoted for clarity, but it is worth pointing out that this doesn't _quite_ preserve the original behavior in the posted code of offering four _total_ opportunities to enter the correct password.  However, if this is an important requirement to the user they can simply increase `counter`.

Comment: @AlexanderNied You're right, but since OP said *The user has 3 attempts to enter the correct password*. So I assume it might be a bug that it actually has 4 attempts...

Comment: Yes, that's a fair assumption.